# ASP.NET Core IdentityServer4 - How can I use Client Login Page instead of IdentityServer Login Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have 2 API, 1 MVC Web App and IdentityServer App in my project.

***Local ports :***

IdentityServer : https://localhost:1000

API 1 : https://localhost:2000

API 2 : https://localhost:3000

Client : https://localhost:4000

In terms of MVC Web App, its Startup.cs Authentication service is like this;

```
services.AddAuthentication(_ =>
{
   DefaultScheme = "...";
   DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("...", options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/home/accessdenied")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", _ =>
{
   _.SignInScheme = "...";
   _.Authority = "https://localhost:1000";
   _.ClientId = "...";
   _.ClientSecret = "...";
   _.ResponseType = "code id_token";
   _.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

   _.SaveTokens = true;
   _.Scope.Add("offline_access");

   _.Scope.Add("...");
   _.Scope.Add("...");
   _.Scope.Add("...");
});
```

In MVC Web app, there is a Controller like this;

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> PayMoney()
{
    var authenticationProperties = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()).Properties.Items;
    string accessToken = authenticationProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == ".Token.access_token").Value;

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:2000/api/.....");
    string total = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return View();
}
```

at this point, I run the apps all together. After that I call PayMoney(above) and then project redirects me to IdentityServer Login Page (**Account/Login**) with ReturnUrl because I am not authenticated and authorized.

But I want to use the login page of MVC App instead of IdentityServer project's Quickstart.UI Login Page

Is it possible? And when I researched people say I should use 'Resource Owner Password' but it is not secure for my project...

*Does anyone have any idea about this ??*

Comment: Like they already told you, if you want to have the login page on your client app, you have to use Resource Owner Password flow, otherwise you have to login from identity server. This is how openid connect works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenID Connect you are not supposed to let the client application see/touch the users username/password. Instead it is by design that the user should be redirected to the identity provider for authentication.

As a client, I would not trust to give my credentials to individual clients, instead you only want to do that to someone you as a user trusts.

Answer (score 1):

In IdentityServer if you want to show your own login screen then you have to implement OpenID Connect by installing the NuGet package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect** in your project. The whole integration procedure is given at this tutorial - [IdentityServer with ASP.NET Core Identity and MongoDB as Database [Detailed Guide]](https://www.yogihosting.com/identityserver-aspnet-core-identity-mongodb-database/).

You can also download the code from this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/yogyogi/IdentityServer-with-ASP.NET-Core-Identity-and-MongoDB-as-Database) which is implemented in .NET 5.0.